# Sending data from android apps to TCP IP

Tags: android, sockets

I am able to connect to TCP IP netwrok but even if i am sending some
byte array but yet i am not seeing any output on Server console.
Server is C++ and i need to send data from my android apps. I am able
to connect but when i send data i am not getting any notification. the
followins is my code.

```
 InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
 SocketAddress socketadd= new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, serverPort);
 Log.d("TCP", "C: Connecting...");

 //Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, serverPort);
 Socket socket=new Socket();

 try {
     Log.d("TCP", "C: Sending: '" + msg + "'");
     socket.connect(socketadd);
     Log.e("Connect:", "Connect:");
     DataOutputStream  dataout = new
     DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     dataout.flush();

     byte haeader[]=new byte[6];
     // String data="20110110,cswxerotest,cswxerotest";
     // Packet p=new Packet();
     //byte bdata[]=converttoCPP(getBytes());

     byte bdata[]=getBytes();
     //byte a[]=new byte[20];

     //dataout.writeByte(5);
     dataout.write(bdata,0,bdata.length);
     dataout.flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a message `msg` to send, but I don't see that you convert it to bytes and send it anywhere (something like `byte bdata[] = msg.getBytes()` )

Comment: HI,thanks for your reply. I have methods in which i am pasing some short and String variables into byte and then i sent that whole byte array. hope to hear soon from you.